# How to avoid terraform previous ec2 to be destroy while creating new one using script

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

Actually i created EC2 Vm using terraform by count first time it got created while try to create another one for example if I gave count 2 it creates only one instance and if I gave count 1 it destroy the previous ones please help me regarding.

```
provider "aws"{
 profile = "default"
 region = var.region    
}

resource "aws_instance" "hello" {   
  count=1  
  ami           = var.ami   
  instance_type = "t2.micro"   
  tags = {    
    Name = "EC2 instance creation"

}    
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that using count parameter. you will have to launch those servers separately. Also there is no way to avoid the destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform creates resources using count based on their index.  If you add or subtract from the count it is count to remove the resource at the index positions that were removed.

If you are creating VMs to be used for different purposes and they are not going to be identical in nature they should be created as a separate resource.

Comment: "If you add or subtract from the count it is count to remove the resource at the index positions that were removed." can you please tell me how to restrict remove